# String code reduction using single regex

Tags: java

I am using these two regex statement. I want to use only one regex rule to reduce code for all type of spaces that come

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");  
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("(\\t)+", " ");
```

what regex I need to use for that??

Answer (score 4):

```
strTestIn = strTestIn.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
```

See the [**Pattern**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) class

`\s` matches whitespace character: `[ \t\n\x0B\f\r]`

Comment: @Јοеу: not quite sure, I copied that sentence from the documentation. I think it would. You could test that.